# Given the set $ A = \{ 0.9, \, 0.919, \, 0.9119, \, 0.91119, \text{...} \} $ find $ \inf A, \sup A, \max A, \min A $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

I'm having some difficulty solving this problem :

> Given the set $$ A = \{ 0.9, \, 0.919, \, 0.9119, \, 0.91119, \text{...} \} $$  find $ \inf A, \sup A, \max A, \min A $.

Let $ A = \{ 0.9 \} \cup  \{ a_n \} $.

Note that the sequence $ a_n $ is decreasing, consequently $ a_n \rightarrow \inf a_n $.

It follows that $$ a_1 = \sup a_n = 0.919 \in A $$

Therefore $$ \sup A = \max A = 0.919 $$

Since $ a_n $ is decreasing

$$ \inf a_n = \lim\limits_{n→∞} a_n $$

This is the part where I got stuck. I need to express $ a_n $ in more traditionally formulaic notation in order to find $ \inf a_n $.

Comment: $\inf a_n=0.9111111...$ but $\inf A = \min A = 0.9$, so why do you need $\inf a_n$?

Comment: $0.9<a_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: $ 0.9 $ and $ \lim\limits_{n→∞} a_n $ are both lower bounds of the set $ A $. Therefore $ \inf A $ = greatest lower bound of $ \{ 0.9, \lim\limits_{n→∞} a_n \} $. So $ 0.9 $ is not necessarily equal to $ \inf A $.

Comment: $0.9\bar 1$ is **not** a lower bound of $A$, as the element $0.9$ is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easily verifies that
$$a_0=0.9={81\over 90},\qquad a_r={82\over90}+{71\over900}\>10^{-r}\quad(r\geq1)\ .$$
It follows that $\inf A=\min A=a_0={9\over10}$, and that $\sup A=\max A=a_1=0.919$.